# PowerShell Workflow not running as intended

Tags: azure, powershell, workflow

I have a PowerShell script which I've converted to a Workflow. The script is near identical, except for the few lines that need to be altered in order for it to be a Workflow.

However, for some reason it doesn't output like I think it should, and I am absolutely clueless as to why this would be the case.

Original PS script:

```
$DynatraceTenantID = "asdf"
$DynatraceToken = "asdf"
$DynatraceServer = "asdf"

$TagName = "env"
$TagValue = "dynatrace"

$result_array_altered = @()
$result_array_installed = @()
$result_array_notaltered = @()

$vms = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -inotlike "MyVMx0"}

Foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vm0 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
    $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
    $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
    if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit"){
        if ($vm0.Statuses.DisplayStatus -eq "VM running") {
            Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
                -Name "Dynatrace" `
                -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
                -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
                -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
                -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
                -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
                -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
                -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }

            $objAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
                IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
                }

            $result_array_altered += $objAltered
            } else {
                $objNotAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    VMnotAltered = $($vm1.Name)
                    IDnotAltered = $($vm1.Id)
                }

                $result_array_notaltered += $objNotAltered
            }
        } else {
            $objInstalled = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
                IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
            }

            $result_array_installed += $objInstalled
        }
    }

$result_array_altered | ConvertTo-Json

$result_array_installed | ConvertTo-Json

$result_array_notaltered | ConvertTo-Json
```

Outputs the following:

```
[
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/MY-SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw0",
        "VMinstalled":  "MyVMw0"
    },
    {
        "IDinstalled":  "/subscriptions/MY-SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw1",
        "VMinstalled":  "MyVMw1"
    }
]
```

The converted PowerShell to PS Workflow:

```
workflow InstallDynatrace {
    $DynatraceTenantID = "asdf"
    $DynatraceToken = "asdf"
    $DynatraceServer = "asdf"

    $TagName = "env"
    $TagValue = "dynatrace"

    $result_array_altered = @()
    $result_array_installed = @()
    $result_array_notaltered = @()

    $vms = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -inotlike "MyVMx0"}

    Foreach -parallel ($vm in $vms) {
        $vm0 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
        $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
        $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
        if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit"){
            if ($vm0.Statuses.DisplayStatus -eq "VM running") {
                Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
                    -Name "Dynatrace" `
                    -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
                    -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
                    -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
                    -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
                    -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
                    -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
                    -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }

                $objAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
                    IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
                    }


                } else {
                    $objNotAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                        VMnotAltered = $($vm1.Name)
                        IDnotAltered = $($vm1.Id)
                    }


                }
            } else {
                $objInstalled = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
                    IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
                }


            }
        $workflow:result_array_altered += $objAltered
        $workflow:result_array_notaltered += $objNotAltered
        $workflow:result_array_installed += $objInstalled
        }

    $result_array_altered | ConvertTo-Json

    $result_array_installed | ConvertTo-Json

    $result_array_notaltered | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> InstallDynatrace
[
    {
        "VMnotAltered":  "MyVMw1",
        "IDnotAltered":  "/subscriptions/MY-SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw1",
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "36c288df-41c3-4b61-9a6c-445707f76bea"
    },
    {
        "VMnotAltered":  "MyVMw0",
        "IDnotAltered":  "/subscriptions/MY-SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw0",
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "36c288df-41c3-4b61-9a6c-445707f76bea"
    }
]
```

Note how the original script shows that results array to be `VMinstalled` and `IDinstalled`, whereas the workflow shows as `VMnotAltered` and `IDnotAltered`, meaning that it saw the VMs as NOT having Dynatrace installed (line 19), didn't see it Running (line 20) and just added it to the Not Altered array.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

***UPDATED FOR THEO ANSWER***

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 
workflow InstallDynatrace {
    $DynatraceTenantID = "asdf"
    $DynatraceToken = "asdf"
    $DynatraceServer = "asdf"

    $TagName = "env"
    $TagValue = "dynatrace"

    $result_array_altered = @()
    $result_array_installed = @()
    $result_array_notaltered = @()

    $vms = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -inotlike "MyVMx0"}

    Foreach -parallel ($vm in $vms) {
        $vm0 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
        $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
        $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
        if ($vm2.Publisher -ne "dynatrace.ruxit"){
            if ($vm0.Statuses.DisplayStatus -eq "VM running") {
                Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
                    -Name "Dynatrace" `
                    -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
                    -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
                    -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
                    -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
                    -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
                    -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
                    -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }

                $objAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
                    IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
                    }

                $workflow:result_array_altered += $objAltered
                } else {
                    $objNotAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                        VMnotAltered = $($vm1.Name)
                        IDnotAltered = $($vm1.Id)
                    }

                $workflow:result_array_notaltered += $objNotAltered
                }
            } else {
                $objInstalled = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
                    IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
                }

                $workflow:result_array_installed += $objInstalled
            }
        }

    $workflow:result_array_altered | ConvertTo-Json
    $workflow:result_array_installed | ConvertTo-Json
    $workflow:result_array_notaltered | ConvertTo-Json
}

InstallDynatrace
[
    {
        "VMnotAltered":  "MyVMw0",
        "IDnotAltered":  "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw0",
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "d23d8e5b-dc3c-475f-82fe-968a3eeef946"
    },
    {
        "VMnotAltered":  "MyVMw1",
        "IDnotAltered":  "/subscriptions/asdf/resourceGroups/virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVMw1",
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "d23d8e5b-dc3c-475f-82fe-968a3eeef946"
    }
]

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made the same error you did earlier I'm afraid.
Where in the script you add the object to the corresponding array where it *should* be added, namely right after creating it inside the `if` or `else` block, in the Workflow you add them all at the end of the loop..

This means that **regardless** of the outcome of the `if {...} else {...}` tests, you add them anyway.

This should do things in the right place:

```
Foreach -parallel ($vm in $vms) {
    $vm0 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
    $vm1 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name
    $vm2 = $vm1.Extensions
    if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit"){  # should be -ne I think
        if ($vm0.Statuses.DisplayStatus -eq "VM running") {
            Set-AzureRmVmExtension `
                -Name "Dynatrace" `
                -Publisher "dynatrace.ruxit" `
                -ResourceGroupName "$($vm1.ResourceGroupName)" `
                -Location "$($vm1.Location)" `
                -VMName "$($vm1.Name)" `
                -ExtensionType "oneAgentWindows" `
                -TypeHandlerVersion "2.3" `
                -Settings @{ "tenantId"=$DynatraceTenantID; "token"=$DynatraceToken;"server"=$DynatraceServer; }

            $objAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                VMaltered = $($vm1.Name)
                IDaltered = $($vm1.Id)
                }
            # this is where you add the object to the $workflow:result_array_altered array
            $workflow:result_array_altered += $objAltered
        } 
        else {
            $objNotAltered = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                VMnotAltered = $($vm1.Name)
                IDnotAltered = $($vm1.Id)
            }
            # this is where you add the object to the $workflow:result_array_notaltered array
            $workflow:result_array_notaltered += $objNotAltered
            }
        } 
    else {
        $objInstalled = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            VMinstalled = $($vm1.Name)
            IDinstalled = $($vm1.Id)
        }
        # this is where you add the object to the $workflow:result_array_installed array
        $workflow:result_array_installed += $objInstalled
    }
}

$workflow:result_array_altered    | ConvertTo-Json
$workflow:result_array_notaltered | ConvertTo-Json
$workflow:result_array_installed  | ConvertTo-Json
```

Then, at the end of the workflow, you outputted the arrays you still had in memory from the earlier script version (`$result_array_altered | ConvertTo-Json` etc. I have changed that to match the new arrays for you.

Also, isn't `$vm2.Publisher` just a single string? In that case, change the lines

```
if ($vm2.Publisher -notcontains "dynatrace.ruxit")
```

into

```
if ($vm2.Publisher -ne "dynatrace.ruxit")
```

(`-notcontains` checks a value in an array where `-ne` tests for the 'not-equalness' of a single object, so a string  in this case)

---

**UPDATE**

I MAY have found an answer for the unwanted extra information [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7579)

It may look ugly, but try this at the end of the workflow:

```
$workflow:result_array_altered    | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, PSSourceJobInstanceId | ConvertTo-Json
$workflow:result_array_installed  | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, PSSourceJobInstanceId | ConvertTo-Json
$workflow:result_array_notaltered | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, PSSourceJobInstanceId | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: thanks for the reply (again:). I had already thought of your answer from my last post and implemented that, but it made no difference. I should have pasted the contents of that instead, before posting. I have updated my question to include your recommendations, but it hasn't changed the output. I've even killed and re-opened PS to clear all $ variables. Top tip on the `-ne` of dynatrace. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Beefcake Weird... I have no idea why it adds extra PSObject information to the output. At first I thought it may have anything to do with Verbose, but doing `ConvertTo-Json -Verbose:$false` seems to not make a difference..

Comment: @Beefcake I did not test (I'm relying on you to do that), but I have updated my answer with a workaround that may do the trick.

Comment: @ Theo, it's not the PS... parts I'm interested in. That's just standard Workflow output. Mine concern is: *Note how the original script shows that results array to be `VMinstalled` and `IDinstalled`, whereas the workflow shows as `VMnotAltered` and `IDnotAltered`, meaning that it saw the VMs as NOT having Dynatrace installed (line 19), didn't see it Running (line 20) and just added it to the Not Altered array*

Comment: just an FYI; the `-ExcludeProperty` didn't work, because it's mandatory for Workflow output

Comment: @Beefcake  Just one more thing I've found. (don't know if this will help at all..). If you do `$vm0 = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status`, you will get an object back that has **two** `Statuses` in the top level. To see the one that has the property you seek (is it running or not), you will want `Statuses[1]`. So what if you change this line `if ($vm0.Statuses.DisplayStatus -eq "VM running")` into this: `if ($vm0.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus -eq "VM running")`?

Comment: sadly this has not made a difference either. I wasn't too sure it would work either, seeing as thou if it wasn't a Runbook it worked. So perplexing...